# capture line fragment from below txt

Tags: c#, regex

I'm try to reading and get specific values from table in txt with regex from a  PDF that was copied.

Eg:

```
DADOS DO FABRICANTE
* CNPJ/CPF           UF    Quantidade Peso Líquido(kg)   Vl.Moeda
- 99.999.999/9999-99 MN    4,00000    212,00000          250.400,00
Obs:
```

In the text above I would to get the value from UF that is MN and other of course like Vl.Moeda

I try this regex but not working very well:

```
[*\n\r\s*]UF\s *.*[^\w]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as result? That's not clear. Are the lines always as you show, starting with a dash (-), then numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult, while your attempt looks great. My guess is that we might want to capture `UF` and  `Vl.Moeda` and associated values, which we might be able to do so, maybe with this expression:

```
\b([A-Z]{2})\b\s{2,}.*\s{2,}(.+)
```

where we'd include a `\s{2,}` to fail other similar texts and then capture our desired outputs in `([A-Z]{2})` and `(.+)`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlR6j6/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\b([A-Z]{2})\b\s{2,}.*\s{2,}(.+)";
        string input = @"DADOS DO FABRICANTE
* CNPJ/CPF           UF    Quantidade Peso Líquido(kg)   Vl.Moeda
- 99.999.999/9999-99 MN    4,00000    212,00000          250.400,00
Obs:
- 99.999.999/9999-99 AB    4,00000    212,00000          250.400,00000
Obs:
- 99.999.999/9999-99 XZ    4,00000    212,00000          250.400,00000
Obs:";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]